# Find closest (above) html element that has disabled attr

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find the closest html input field that has disabled attribute .

HTML structure is :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input  type="text" disabled class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="toggle switch-animate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

What i have tried so far but not working:

```
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        if ($(this).closest("input").attr("disabled"){
            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse up to the overall container then use `find()` with an attribute selector

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  if ($(this).closest(".form-group").find("[disabled]").length) {
    console.log("The paragraph was clicked.");
    $(this).closest(".form-group").find("[disabled]").prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" disabled class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="toggle switch-animate">
      toggle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanls. And for example how can i remove the disabled attr for the found disabled field.? Thanks in advance

Comment: upvoted, because my error was ```find(':disabled')``` instead of ```find('[disabled'])```